# Which languages have support for return value caching without boilerplate code?

Tags: c#, java, performance, language-agnostic, caching

For methods where ...

- there exists a static one-to-one mapping between the input and the output, and
- the cost of creating the output object is relatively high, and
- the method is called repeatedly with the same input

... there is a need for caching result values.

In my code the following result value caching pattern is repeated a lot (pseudo-code in Java, but the question is language-agnostic):

```
private static Map<Input, Output> fooResultMap = new HashMap<Input, Output>();
public getFoo(Input input) {
  if (fooResultMap.get(input) != null) {
    return fooResultMap.get(input);
  }
  Output output = null;
  // Some code to obtain the object since we don't have it in the cache.
  fooResultMap.put(input, output);
  return output;
}
```

Repeating this structure all the time is a clear violation of the DRY principle.

Ideally, I'd like the code above to be reduced to the following:

```
@CacheResult
public getFoo(Input input) {
  Output output = null;
  // Some code to obtain the object since we don't have it in the cache.
  return output;
}
```

Where the theoretical CacheResult annotation would take care of the caching I'm currently doing by hand.

The general term for this type of caching is "[memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)".

A good example of the exact functionality I'm looking for is [Perl core module "Memoize"](http://perldoc.perl.org/Memoize.html).

**In which languages does such a Memoize-like caching solution exist (either at the language level or the library level)? In particular - does such a solution exist for any major platform such as Java or .NET?**

Comment: (Note, the code shown leaks and is not thread-safe.)

Comment: This is running a web context, and where you have to get the value of Foo from a database each time?

Comment: @Chris: No, the question is context-neutral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a language built-in, put the CPAN module [Memoize](http://search.cpan.org/~mjd/Memoize-1.01/Memoize.pm) is reasonably popular in Perl land, I think:

```
   # Compute Fibonacci numbers
    sub fib {
      my $n = shift;
      return $n if $n < 2;
      fib($n-1) + fib($n-2);
    }

    use Memoize;
    memoize('fib');
```

Comment: Thanks! That's an exact match, and actually it's a core Perl module!

Answer (score 2):

The Caching Handler - in .Net 'Enterprise Library'

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511757.aspx

```
[CachingCallHandler(0, 0, 30)]
public decimal GetSavingsBalance(int accountNumber)
{
  // Code here to extract balance from database.
  return balance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a number of decorator recipes, e.g. the [decorator module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator/3.0.0), that work for this (*if* the parameters are all immutable), and it has implementations on both the JVM and .NET.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring's incubation area, **[springmodules](https://springmodules.dev.java.net)** has exactly this functionality for Java.

**[Springmodules cache](https://springmodules.dev.java.net/docs/reference/0.8/html/cache.html)** is still at 0.8 release level, but it worked generally quite well when I tried it last year.  There are options to configure the caching within spring configuration files as well as with annotations - which looks pretty much exactly like your example.  From their docs:

```
public class TigerCacheableService implements CacheableService {

  @Cacheable(modelId = "testCaching")
  public final String getName(int index) {
    // some implementation.
  }
...
}
```

You can choose the back end implementation of the cache.  When I was trying it I had good results hooking it up to [ehcache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/) which has nice spring integration too.  You can declaratively set up ehcache to cache (in-memory and/or disk) the results of the methods that you tag with the **`@Cacheable`** annotation.

Comment: Can you use the @Cacheable annotation without any Spring configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `@CacheResult` annotation in Java, using for example [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) to [transform](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cwt06075/) the method to add the memoization code.

Comment: This: http://www.tek271.com/?about=software/java/memoizer/tek271.memoizer.intro.html seems like it's actually doing this for java

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft T-SQL can cache the return values from a CLR function on a pr. query basis...

(No boilerplate except the correct attributes on the method when writing it in CLR.)

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you are maintaining many caches, it may be worthwhile to use [OSCache](http://www.opensymphony.com/oscache/) (Java) for management of those caches. Eviction of stale objects etc, becomes a problem you don't have to worry about.

You would still have to use the basic pattern of "check cache", "return cached" or "create and add to cache" though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of OSCache and it's benefits over HashMap, but the code I provided is just pseudo-code to show the mechanism. I don't think OSCache provides any "memoize" functionality.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to factor out code like that in Java, although Java's syntax remains verbose

```
private static final Cache<Input, Output> fooCache = Caches.newInstance(
    new Factory<Input, Output>() { public Output create(Input input) {
        return ... some code ...;
    }}
);
public static Output getFoo(Input input) {
    return fooCache.get(input);
}
```

With better syntactical support for anonymous inner classes, that could become, say:

```
private static final Cache<Input, Output> fooCache =
    (Input input) (... some code ...);
public static Output getFoo(Input input) {
    return fooCache.get(input);
}
```

This is one thing that AOP solution can do, at the expense of having to deal with a bit of magic.

Comment: As you point out that's still very verbose. I'm looking for something more lean à la "memoize" in Perl or Python.

Comment: I wouldn't call it *very* verbose in the scheme of things.

Comment: @knorv: the reason you cannot do what perl/python does in java is because in java, functions are not first class citizens, and so you cannot decorate a function. The memoization process is tightly coupled to the type it is storing, and that is the result of the type system in java. dont think it can be avoided. A language that automatically "memoizes" for you is a functional language like haskell =)

Answer (score -1):

[This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633508/two-argument-memoization) addresses Memoization in C#. It doesn't cache the results, but could be easily changed to make the map static with a ReaderWriterLock.

Here's a sample from the [link given](http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2007/01/26/function-memoization.aspx):

```
public static Func<A, R> Memoize<A, R>(this Func<A, R> f)
{
  var map = new Dictionary<A, R>();
  return a =>
    {
      R value;
      if (map.TryGetValue(a, out value))
        return value;
      value = f(a);
      map.Add(a, value);
      return value;
    };
}
```