# C# Memoization of functions with arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: c#, performance, function, memoization

I'm trying to create a memoization interface for functions with arbitrary number of arguments, but <strike>I'm failing miserably</strike> I feel like my solution is not very flexible. I tried to define an interface for a function which gets memoized automatically upon execution and each function will have to implement this interface. Here is an example with a two parameter Exponential Moving Average function:

```
class EMAFunction:IFunction
{
    Dictionary<List<object>, List<object>> map;

    class EMAComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<object>>
    {
        private int _multiplier = 97;

        public bool Equals(List<object> a, List<object> b)
        {
            List<object> aVals = (List<object>)a[0];
            int aPeriod = (int)a[1];

            List<object> bVals = (List<object>)b[0];
            int bPeriod = (int)b[1];

            return (aVals.Count == bVals.Count) && (aPeriod == bPeriod);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(List<object> obj)
        {
            // Don't compute hash code on null object.
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            List<object> vals = (List<object>) obj[0];
            int period = (int) obj[1];

            return (_multiplier * period.GetHashCode()) + vals.Count;

        }
    }

    public EMAFunction()
    {
        NumParams = 2;
        Name = "EMA";
        map = new Dictionary<List<object>, List<object>>(new EMAComparer());
    }
    #region IFunction Members

    public int NumParams
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public object Execute(List<object> parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.Count != NumParams)
            throw new ArgumentException("The num params doesn't match!");

        if (!map.ContainsKey(parameters))
        {
            //map.Add(parameters,
            List<double> values = new List<double>();
            List<object> asObj = (List<object>)parameters[0];
            foreach (object val in asObj)
            {
                values.Add((double)val);
            }
            int period = (int)parameters[1];

            asObj.Clear();
            List<double> ema = TechFunctions.ExponentialMovingAverage(values, period);
            foreach (double val in ema)
            {
                asObj.Add(val);
            }
            map.Add(parameters, asObj);
        }
        return map[parameters];
    }

    public void ClearMap()
    {
        map.Clear();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here are my tests of the function:

```
private void MemoizeTest()
{
    DataSet dataSet = DataLoader.LoadData(DataLoader.DataSource.FROM_WEB, 1024);
    List<String> labels = dataSet.DataLabels;

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    IFunction emaFunc = new EMAFunction();
    List<object> parameters = new List<object>();
    int numRuns = 1000;
    long sumTicks = 0;
    parameters.Add(dataSet.GetValues("open"));
    parameters.Add(12);

    // First call

    for(int i = 0; i < numRuns; ++i)
    {
        emaFunc.ClearMap();// remove any memoization mappings
        sw.Start();
        emaFunc.Execute(parameters);
        sw.Stop();
        sumTicks += sw.ElapsedTicks;
        sw.Reset();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Average ticks not-memoized " + (sumTicks/numRuns));


    sumTicks = 0;
    // Repeat call
    for (int i = 0; i < numRuns; ++i)
    {
        sw.Start();
        emaFunc.Execute(parameters);
        sw.Stop();
        sumTicks += sw.ElapsedTicks;
        sw.Reset();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Average ticks memoized " + (sumTicks/numRuns));
}
```

**Update:**
Thanks for pointing out my n00bish error... I **always** forget to call Reset on the stopwatch!

I've seen [another approach to memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633508/two-argument-memoization) as well... it doesn't offer n-argument memoization, but my approach with the Interface is not much more advantageous since I have to write a class for each function. Is there a reasonable way that I can merge these ideas into something more robust? **I want to make it easier to memoize a function without making the user write a class for each function that they intend to use.**

Answer (score 88, accepted):

How about this? First write a one-argument memoizer:

```
static Func<A, R> Memoize<A, R>(this Func<A, R> f)
{
    var d = new Dictionary<A, R>();
    return a=> 
    {
        R r;
        if (!d.TryGetValue(a, out r))
        {
            r = f(a);
            d.Add(a, r);
        }
        return r;
    };
}
```

Straightforward. Now write a function tuplifier:

```
static Func<Tuple<A, B>, R> Tuplify<A, B, R>(this Func<A, B, R> f)
{
    return t => f(t.Item1, t.Item2);
}
```

And a detuplifier:

```
static Func<A, B, R> Detuplify<A, B, R>(this Func<Tuple<A, B>, R> f)
{
    return (a, b) => f(Tuple.Create(a, b));
}
```

and now a two-argument memoizer is easy:

```
static Func<A, B, R> Memoize<A, B, R>(this Func<A, B, R> f)
{
    return f.Tuplify().Memoize().Detuplify();
}
```

To write a three-argument memoizer just keep following this pattern: make a 3-tuplifier, a 3-untuplifier, and a 3-memoizer.

Of course, if you don't need them, there's no need to make the tuplifiers nominal methods:

```
static Func<A, B, R> Memoize<A, B, R>(this Func<A, B, R> f)
{
    Func<Tuple<A, B>, R> tuplified = t => f(t.Item1, t.Item2);
    Func<Tuple<A, B>, R> memoized = tuplified.Memoize();
    return (a, b) => memoized(Tuple.Create(a, b));
}
```

UPDATE: You ask what to do if there is no tuple type. You could write your own; it's not hard. Or you could use anonymous types:

```
static Func<T, R> CastByExample<T, R>(Func<T, R> f, T t) { return f; }

static Func<A, B, R> Memoize<A, B, R>(this Func<A, B, R> f)
{
    var example = new { A=default(A), B=default(B) };
    var tuplified = CastByExample(t => f(t.A, t.B), example);
    var memoized = tuplified.Memoize();
    return (a, b) => memoized(new {A=a, B=b});
}
```

Slick, eh?

---

UPDATE: C# 7 now has value tuples built in to the language; use them rather than rolling your own or using anonymous types.

Comment: that's a great idea... unfortunately I'm using .NET 3.5 and I won't be able to switch to 4.0 for some time. Is there a .NET 3.5 compatible version of the above?

Comment: @Lirik: writing your own tuple type is not very hard. The trick is to make sure that you get the equality and hash code computation correct.  Or, there are really tricky ways to make this work with anonymous types, which are effectively the same as tuples.

Comment: I love the anon type as an arbitrary tuple, you might want to point out that when you hit the wall in regards to system defined [Func<...> ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx) you do need to start implementing your own. Gotta say if you're doing this it's perhaps time to consider f# as a possible candidate language...

Comment: oh and a link to [CastByExample](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2007/11/22/t-castbyexample-t-object-o-t-example.aspx)

Comment: and @ShuggyCoUK, that's amazing! I can't believe it works so well! If I could up-vote this answer more than once, **I would**! LOL

Comment: Hi! I've made the memoization from the first code-block thread-safe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544641/how-to-perform-thread-safe-function-memoization-in-c :)

Comment: What did I just read? O_O

Comment: @EricLippert Can you please explain why `Memoize()` creates a new `Dictionary` on every call?  Shouldn't the cache be part of the state and not a local variable to the function?

Comment: @dashnick: I'm not following your line of thought here. Tell you what: write an implementation of `Memoize(f)` that does not create a new dictionary on every call, and we'll compare your implementation to mine.

Comment: @EricLippert - I see my mistake - was thinking of `Memoize()` had a signature more like `static R Memoize<R>(this Func<A, R> f)`, i.e. you would call `Memoize()` instead of the original function, not a function that `Memoize()` returns.  In my case obviously there'd be multiple calls and you'd have to store the dictionary in state, whereas your implementation returns a closure I believe.

Comment: @dashnick: That's correct. Glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 3):

StopWatch.Stop does not reset the stopwatch so you are accumulating time on each start/stop.

For example

```
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

  sw.Start();
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
  sw.Stop();
  Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);

  sw.Start();
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
  sw.Stop();
  Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
```

Gives the following results

```
228221
454626
```

You can use `StopWatch.Restart` (Framework 4.0) to restart the stopwatch each time, or if not Framework 4.0, you can use `StopWatch.Reset` to reset the stopwatch.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to call `sw.Reset()` between your tests. Otherwise your results for the second test will be *in addition* to the time from the first.

Second, you probably shouldn't use `vals.GetHashCode()` in your `GetHashCode()` override on the comparer, as this will lead you to getting different hash codes for objects that would evaluate to `true` for your `Equals` override. For now, I would worry about making sure that equivalent objects *always* get the same hash code rather than trying to get an even distribution of the codes. If the hash codes don't match, `Equals` will never be called, so you'll end up processing the same parameters multiple times.

Comment: OK, I fixed the GetHashCode function and I called Reset... things look much better now. I also saw another good way to get the memoization done, any suggestions on how it can be generalized: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633508/two-argument-memoization

Answer (score 2):

Alternative (to tuples & anonymous types) approach might be as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var func = Memoize<int, int, int>(Func);

    Console.WriteLine(func(3)(4));
    Console.WriteLine(func(3)(5));
    Console.WriteLine(func(2)(5));
    Console.WriteLine(func(3)(4));
}

//lets pretend this is very-expensive-to-compute function
private static int Func(int i, int j)
{
    return i + j;
}

private static Func<TArg1, Func<TArg2, TRes>> Memoize<TArg1, TArg2, TRes>(Func<TArg1, TArg2, TRes> func)
{
     Func<TArg1, Func<TArg2, TRes>> func1 = 
        Memoize((TArg1 arg1) => Memoize((TArg2 arg2) => func(arg1, arg2)));

    return func1;
}

private static Func<TArg, TRes> Memoize<TArg, TRes>(Func<TArg, TRes> func)
{
    var cache = new Dictionary<TArg, TRes>();

    return arg =>
    {
        TRes res;

        if( !cache.TryGetValue(arg, out res) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calculating " + arg.ToString());

            res = func(arg);

            cache.Add(arg, res);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting from cache " + arg.ToString());
        }

        return res;
    };
}
```

Based on these two Memoize funcs you can easily build extensions for as many args as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I initially came here just looking for an abstract memoization method for a no-parameter function.  This isn't exactly an answer to the question but wanted to share my solution in case someone else came looking for the simple case.

```
public static class MemoizationExtensions
{
    public static Func<R> Memoize<R>(this Func<R> f)
    {
        bool hasBeenCalled = false; // Used to determine if we called the function and the result was the same as default(R)
        R returnVal = default(R);
        return () =>
        {
            // Should be faster than doing null checks and if we got a null the first time, 
            // we really want to memoize that result and not inadvertently call the function again.
            if (!hasBeenCalled)
            {
                hasBeenCalled = true;
                returnVal = f();
            }
            return returnVal;
        };
    }
}
```

If you use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) you can use the following code to easily test out the functionality through the use of LinqPad's super cool **Dump** method.

```
new List<Func<object>>(new Func<object>[] {
        () => { "Entered func A1".Dump(); return 1; },
        () => { "Entered func A2".Dump(); return default(int); },
        () => { "Entered func B1".Dump(); return String.Empty; },
        () => { "Entered func B2".Dump(); return default(string); },
        () => { "Entered func C1".Dump(); return new {Name = String.Empty}; },
        () => { "Entered func C2".Dump(); return null; },
    })
    .ForEach(f => {
        var f1 = MemoizationExtensions.Memoize(f);
        Enumerable
            .Range(1,3)
            .Select(i=>new {Run=i, Value=f1()})
            .Dump();
    });
```

P.S. You will need to include the MemoizationExtensions class in the code of the **LinqPad** script otherwise it won't work!