# Implementing memoization in C#

Tags: c#, functional-programming, memoization

I know this topic (memoization) has been discussed quite a bit (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852161/c-sharp-memoization-of-functions-with-arbitrary-number-of-arguments)), but no answer I could find satisfies the DRY principle as much as I would like, so please, read this whole question and the three points I want to address.

I have a simple support class like this:

```
public class Memoized<T1, TResult>
{
    private readonly Func<T1, TResult> _f;

    private readonly Dictionary<T1, TResult> _cache = new Dictionary<T1, TResult>();

    public Memoized(Func<T1, TResult> f)
    {
        _f = f;
    }

    public TResult Invoke(T1 p1)
    {
        if (p1 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(p1));

        if (_cache.TryGetValue(p1, out var res)) return res;

        return _cache[p1] = _f(p1);
    }
    public static Func<T1, TResult> Of(Func<T1, TResult> f)
    {
        var memo = new Memoized<T1, TResult>(f);

        return x => memo.Invoke(x);
    }
}
```

Nothing especially fancy, but it allows me to do this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Func<int, bool> MemoizedMethod { get; }

    private bool UncachedMethod(int v)
    {
        return v > 0;
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        MemoizedMethod = Memoized<int, bool>.Of(UncachedMethod);
    }
}
```

Now, even if the resulting code is not terribly noisy, **I'm trying to figure out if the implementation could be more elegant, because currently I need**:

1. an invokable property that acts as a Method.
2. a true method that should not be called directly.
3. a line in the constructor (cannot be an inline initialization) that links the two (with a third repetition of the function signature!).

Any suggestion for a strategy that allows to remove one (or two!) of the above points would be great.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily make sense to implement memoization in a generic way, rather this is something you should do on a case-by-case basis where you expect to see a performance improvement. I.e. when the cost of maintaining a cache of memoized results is less than the cost of recalculating them.

Comment: Uh, no. It needs to be generic: because I will need it many times. Not everywhere, obviously, but a lot of times, yes (I'm working on a 40k LOC project). So, I need a syntax that is the most compact and error free. In a word, elegant. I dont' want to fill all my classes with caching dictionaries and repeated structure.

Comment: This looks like [Lazy<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netcore-2.1)

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` is all you need. Make a key out of your argument, then just do return `internalDictionary.GetOrAdd(argumentKey, internalFunction)`

Comment: @Ben You're assuming a requirement of multithreaded access that doesn't appear to be there.

Comment: @Silvermind, would you mind explaining how you would use `Lazy<T>`? @Ben `ConcurrentDictionary` is similar, but still you need one property (the dictionary), one method(the implementation). Possibly you get rid of the inizialitazion in the constructor?

Comment: @Ben Synchronizing access from multiple threads has a cost.  Potentially a very high cost.  Adding that cost when it's not needed is very ill advised.

Comment: @Ben, I'm fine using ConcurrentDictionary: it seems reasonable. But I'm really interested in getting the _usage syntax_ right: repeating the same signature 3 times seems just wrong to me.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, you need the types. Even using a static, non generic support class with a generic method doesn't get the job done.

Comment: @Ben I already tried it and it works in this simplistic example, but you can't use non-static properties in the code (no `this`). So it is overly restrictive for real life implementations.

Comment: You might look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852161/c-sharp-memoization-of-functions-with-arbitrary-number-of-arguments

Comment: @Silvermind: `Lazy<T>` is best when you have a single value that must be computed lazily from a `Func<T>` Memoization is used to solve the more general problem of I have a `Func<A, R>` and wish to make a new `Func<A, R>` that calls the original if the R for a particular A has not been computed, and then stores the result for next time.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, I was looking into the definition of the term and based upon reading the post I figured I must be missing something. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376646/is-searching-for-duplicates-becoming-a-biased-toward-closing)

Comment: If you want to be elegant af, steal the concept of using Castle to proxy a class from Moq. You can intercept actual method calls and property uses and memoize the hell out of it.

Comment: @Will: [System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy) can accomplish that pretty cleanly, but forces you to extract an interface from the relevant classes.  If you prefer to do massive setup and then have a generalized, easily used memoize attribute, an alternative approach is to write a post-processing tool that modifies your compiled code to wrap it in Memoizers.  The latter approach is pretty straightforward, if you don't mind using expensive (~$600/developer) third-party tools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my struggle for elegance, I finally found what I think is the best syntax I saw anywhere:

```
private class MemoizedTest
{
    private int _counter = 0;

    public int Method(int p) => this.Memoized(p, x =>
    {
        return _counter += x;
    });
}
```

Implementation (one pretty small extension class):

```
namespace System
{
    public static class MemoizerExtension
    {
        internal static ConditionalWeakTable<object, ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>> _weakCache =
            new ConditionalWeakTable<object, ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>>();

        public static TResult Memoized<T1, TResult>(
            this object context,
            T1 arg,
            Func<T1, TResult> f,
            [CallerMemberName] string? cacheKey = null)
            where T1 : notnull
        {
            if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            if (cacheKey == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cacheKey));

            var objCache = _weakCache.GetOrCreateValue(context);

            var methodCache = (ConcurrentDictionary<T1, TResult>) objCache
                .GetOrAdd(cacheKey, _ => new ConcurrentDictionary<T1, TResult>());

            return methodCache.GetOrAdd(arg, f);
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**
In the implementation I'm using a `ConditionalWeakTable` for caching, effectively extending the internal structure of the object invoking the memoization. As an additional key, the `CallerMemberName` is used, acting as a second key (this allows more memoizations for instance, and optionally more memoizations per method, if passing the `cacheKey` parameter explicitly).
The third key is the parameter of the invocation.

So, we have 3 runtime dictionary-like searches instead of 1, but a syntax that is a lot cleaner, IMO.

Is it worth it? I dunno, but my desire for elegance is satiated.

If someone else is interested, I'm including the tests for reference:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MemoizerTest
{
    [Test]
    public void MemoizationWorksOnFuncs()
    {
        int counter = 0;

        Func<int, int> f = x => counter += x;

        Assert.That(this.Memoized(1, f), Is.EqualTo(1));

        Assert.That(this.Memoized(2, f), Is.EqualTo(3));

        Assert.That(this.Memoized(2, f), Is.EqualTo(3));

        Assert.That(this.Memoized(1, f), Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    private class MemoizedTest
    {
        private int _counter = 0;

        public int Method(int p)
            => this.Memoized(p, x => { return _counter += x; });
    }

    [Test]
    public void MemoizationWorksOnInstances()
    {
        var obj1 = new MemoizedTest();

        Assert.That(obj1.Method(5), Is.EqualTo(5));
        Assert.That(obj1.Method(4), Is.EqualTo(9));
        Assert.That(obj1.Method(5), Is.EqualTo(5));
        Assert.That(obj1.Method(1), Is.EqualTo(10));
        Assert.That(obj1.Method(4), Is.EqualTo(9));

        obj1 = new MemoizedTest();

        Assert.That(obj1.Method(5), Is.EqualTo(5));
        Assert.That(obj1.Method(4), Is.EqualTo(9));
        Assert.That(obj1.Method(5), Is.EqualTo(5));
        Assert.That(obj1.Method(1), Is.EqualTo(10));
        Assert.That(obj1.Method(4), Is.EqualTo(9));
    }

    [Test]
    [Ignore("This test passes only when compiled in Release mode")]
    public void WeakMemoizationCacheIsCleared()
    {
        var obj1 = new MemoizedTest();

        var r1 = obj1.Method(5);

        MemoizerExtension._weakCache.TryGetValue(obj1, out var cache);

        var weakRefToCache = new WeakReference(cache);

        cache = null;
        GC.Collect(2);

        obj1 = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.Collect();

        var msg = weakRefToCache.TrackResurrection;

        Assert.That(weakRefToCache.IsAlive, Is.False, "The weak reference should be dead.");

        Assert.That(r1, Is.EqualTo(5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you capture the dictionary in the lambda, your state will be maintained implicitly.

```
public class Memoized
{
    // Example with a single parameter. That parameter becomes the key to the dictionary.
    public static Func<T1, TRet> Of<T1, TRet>(Func<T1, TRet> f)
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary<T1, TRet> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<T1, TRet>();
        return (arg1) => cache.GetOrAdd(arg1, xarg=>f(xarg));
    }
    // Example with two parameters. The key is a tuple, and it must be unpacked before calling func.
    // Three or more parameters generalize from this
    public static Func<T1, T2, TRet> Of<T1, T2, TRet>(Func<T1, T2, TRet> f)
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<T1,T2>, TRet> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<T1, T2>, TRet>();
        return (arg1, arg2) => cache.GetOrAdd(new Tuple<T1,T2>(arg1, arg2), 
            (xarg)=>f(xarg.Item1, xarg.Item2)
            );
    }

}
```

Usage example:

```
class Test
{
    public int Method(String s, String s2)
    {
        return 99;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static bool UncachedMethod(int x) { return x > 0; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cached = Memoized.Of<int,bool>(UncachedMethod);

        var exampleCall = cached(44);
        var exampleCall2 = cached(44);

        // Capture a non-static member function
        var x = new Test();
        var cachedX = Memoized.Of<String, String,int>(x.Method);

        var exampleCall3 = cachedX("a","b");

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but I note that it might be better to use value tuples in C# 7.

Comment: Did this post get only the second up-vote ever by @EricLippert?

Comment: All the examples assume at least one argument; what would be a good approach for parameterless calls?

Comment: @x0n, for parameterless calls you can use Lazy<T>.

Comment: @Ben, several improvements for the single parameter implementation to support null values for input argument:

`public static Func<T1, TRet> Of<T1, TRet>( Func<T1, TRet> f )
{
 Lazy<TRet>? nullArgFactory = null;
 if (default(T1) == null)
  nullArgFactory = new Lazy<TRet>(() => f(default!));
#pragma warning disable CS8714 // Note: we are using separate branch for null values.
 var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<T1, TRet>();
#pragma warning restore CS8714
 return arg => {
  if (arg == null)
   return nullArgFactory!.Value;
  return cache.GetOrAdd(arg, f);
 };
}`